# uinavigationcontroller back button font change not quite correct

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller

I'm doing the following in my code to change the font of the back button:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor whiteColor],UITextAttributeTextColor,[UIFont fontWithName:@"Freshman" size:13.0f],UITextAttributeFont, nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

But the word "Back" is awkwardly towards the top of the back button, not centered to fit it like it normally does. I'm talking about it being centered in regards to the top and bottom, not from right to left. How can I fix this? It seems like I can only change the Shadow and ShadowOffset using the UITextAttributeShadow, so I don't know how to make it look centered.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0, 10) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Please Check [**Reference**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html) Docs

Comment: yeah -- just found out about this. I put it in my code and the app didn't crash this time, but nothing changed. It is still not correctly aligned.

Comment: it's setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment, if you want to edit your answer

Comment: No problem. Mind sharing why it wasn't working for you at first?

Comment: Ah, good catch. Confusing that there's a whole different method just for that back button, when the backBarButtonItem is in fact a UIBarButtonItem according to docs.